# Angular proxy and cookies from other domain

Tags: angular, cookies, proxy

I came up with this proxy setup for my Angular application:

proxy.conf.js:

```
const proxy = {
  '/ab': {
    target: 'http://domain.pl',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    cookieDomainRewrite: {
      'domain.pl/ab': 'localhost',
    },
    logLevel: 'debug',
    onProxyRes: function(proxyRes, req, res) {

      if (proxyRes.headers['Set-Cookie']) {
        const cookies = proxyRes.headers['Set-Cookie'].map(cookie => {
          return cookie.replace(/; secure/gi, '');
        });
        proxyRes.headers['Set-Cookie'] = cookies;
      }
    },
    onProxyReq: function(proxyReq, req, res) {
      // proxyReq.setHeader('Cookie', 'JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    },
  },
};

module.exports = proxy;
```

I want to do connect development environment localhost:4200 with backend that is on domain.pl/ab
The thing is that backend is using Spring Security to connect with third party site for login, and after login cookie with JSESSIONID is set on domain.pl/ab and this cookie is used for authorization. Is there a way to catch by proxy request that is comming from browser domain.pl to domain.pl/ab and use JSSESIONID that is in this request to run localhost?
When I copy JSESSIONID from browser domain.pl to a commented code everything is working as expected.